# Is a Sidekick's base +2 proficiency bonus already included in their source stat block?

Tags: dnd-5e, sidekick

I'm confused by the Sidekick rules in *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*. In the "Gaining a Sidekick Class" section, it says this:

> **Proficiency Bonus**
>
> The sidekick's proficiency bonus is determined by its level in its class, as shown in the class's table. Whenever the sidekick's proficiency bonus increases by 1, add 1 to the to-hit modifier of all the attacks in its stat block, and increase the DCs in its stat block by 1.

So when I'm building a level 1 sidekick, is the listed +2 proficiency bonus considered two instances of "proficiency bonus increases by 1", or is the creature considered to *already* have a +2 bonus, and only gets to upgrade attacks and saves once it reaches a proficiency bonus of +3 on the relevant sidekick class table?

As a specific example, a Bandit has a Dexterity bonus of +1 and his two attacks (scimitar and crossbow) both have a +3 bonus, implying a pre-existing proficiency of +2.

So when he becomes a sidekick and gains a level of Expert, do his attacks still have a +3 attack bonus or do they suddenly become +5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### +2 should NOT be added at Sidekick level 1

NPCs and monsters actually already have a proficiency bonus before becoming a sidekick, it just isn't always shown in their stat block. D&D Beyond does include it, as well as some printed sourcebooks, but it seems to be entirely dependent on the monster's Challenge rating based on this table available in the [Basic Rules](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf) (p. 112):

> [image: Proficiency Bonus by Challenge Rating]

Sidekicks (officially) can only be made from monster stat blocks with Challenge rating 1/2 or less, so their proficiency bonus doesn't "increase" when they become a level 1 sidekick, and thus no change to the stat block is necessary.

Comment: Well that's a little bonus DDB gives you, then. The Monster Manual version of the Bandit does not list an explicit Proficiency Bonus.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym I think recent printings should?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I have the Nov. 2018 box set, which is the 9th printing and had all the errata added in, and it doesn't have proficiency bonuses listed.  I can't speak to anything printed after that.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym I'll update the answer; I don't know which sourcebooks would have it but the Basic Rules have a "Proficiency Bonus by Challenge Rating" table rather than explicitly listing it per stat block. It isn't exclusively a D&D Beyond feature though, the stat blocks in Candledeep Mysteries have it stated as well.

Comment: @KamilDrakari Seeing that chart actually made me think I'd seen it before, and yes, I found it -- it's in the monster manual on page 8, in the introduction section that I almost never look at, near the section about Skills. Thanks!  I still think the sidekick rules could've stood to mention outright that all the viable monster statblocks have an included +2 prof bonus, though.